# Terraform aws - Will changing the module for creating s3 bucket of same name delete the s3 bucket and re-create it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform, I have created an s3 bucket in aws "sample-s3" using a module.

After some time I decided to change the module used for creating the s3 bucket. But the existing s3 bucket should not be deleted and re-created. is that possible? Could someone help me out?

Comment: Do you have any reproducible example of which your code and changes you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete that s3 bucket from terraform state with terraform state rm command and then import with new structure after you will change your module.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Let me try this out. For now, I have not removed the old module, keeping both the modules seems to be working fine. Though the code looks redundant